# Como adicionar novos domínios na certificação SSL do Let's Encrypt, mantendo os certificados existentes?

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, https

Eu já tenho alguns domínios usando o certificado SSL da Let's Encrypt.

Através do comando `certbot-auto`, eu faço a instalação de um certificado para determinado domínio. Por exemplo:

```
sudo certbot-auto --apache -d meusite.com
```

Como posso fazer para adicionar novos domínios nesse mesmo certificado?

Ou seja, quero executar esse comando para certificar outros domínios, porém gostaria de manter os que já estão funcionando.

Comment: E eu aqui não estou conseguindo colocar nem 1. heuhuhe

Comment: @acklay qual é a sua dificuldade, jovem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para fazer isso, basta utilizar o comando `certbot-auto` combinado com a opção `--expand`, e `-d`, para adicionar os domínios desejados.

```
  sudo certbot-auto --expand -d dominio1.com.br,dominio2.com.br
```

No meu caso, o certificado adicionado estava expirado, talvez por se tratar de um domínio antigo, então precisei rodar, após a etapa acima, o comando `sudo certbot-auto renew`.